# My Image Modal isn't working after changing from ID to Class

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an image modal and I had it on the image from ID which obviously didn't work, so I changed id to class and now the image modal isn't working at all and I can't see what's wrong with it. All and any help is appreciated.

HTML Modal

```
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                <span class="close">x</span>

                <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

                <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>
```

Image PHP

```
"<tr><td><img class='myImg' src='" . $fileName . "' alt=' ". $obj->Description . "' width='50px'>" .
```

Javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
for(var i=0; i<img.length; i++){
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img[i].addEventListener = ('click', function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    })
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    const key = event.key;
    if (key === "Escape") {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
})

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: `isn't working`...means what exactly? Not displaying? Not hiding? not something else? Be specific about the problem please, and make sure your code contains a [mre] of the issue - i.e. if we ran that code, we'd be able to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event listener in the `for` loop is wrong. You are currently assigning the callback function to the `addEventListener` method.

```js
img[i].addEventListener = ('click', function(){
```

This should be:

```js
img[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
```